# How to get a record's column names using CF Reactor?

Tags: coldfusion, reactor

I'd like to get a list/array of a record object's column names. I suppose I could get this by looping thru the method names, but I was hoping that there would be something cleaner?

Comment: I've not actually used Reactor, but if you dump a Reactor object, are there properties you can access, or potentially a method that will return that information? What does a Reactor object actually look like? The documentation (what I could find) was terrible.

Comment: yah I looked at the methods provided already, and there wasn't anything useful there, but I was hoping that I missed something.

Comment: I went through the SVN repository a bit, and would the `_getObjectMetadata` method get you want you're after?

Comment: It looks like `_getObjectMetadata().getFields()` should get you everything.

Comment: yep that seems to be exactly what I want! want to answer the question quickly and I'll pick it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_getObjectMetadata().getFields()` to get all of the fields on a Reactor object :)